# Selecting calendar date from JavaScriptExecutor in selenium

Tags: javascript, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to select calendar date from JavaScriptExecutor in selenium but the date is not getting selected nor console is giving any error for that. I am not able to understand the reason behind this. Can anyone please help. Below is the selenium code that I have written.

```java
package SeleniumSessions;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SelectCalendarByJS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","F:\\Drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");

        //WebElement date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'fsw_inputBox dates inactiveWidget ']"));

        WebElement date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id = 'departure']"));

        String dateVal = "Friday, 19 Jun 2020";

        selectDateByJS(driver, date, dateVal);

        //driver.quit();

    }

    public static void selectDateByJS(WebDriver driver , WebElement element , String dateVal) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+dateVal+"');", element);

    }
}
```

And below is the HTML DOM for the attribute I am selecting.

```html
<input data-cy="departure" id="departure" type="text" class="fsw_inputField font20" readonly="" value="Friday, 19 Jun 2020">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with makemytrip departure date picker element is you can't send the keys to it. Your code could work for the Expedia application where you can change the value attribute of the text field and that will work. But in the case of makemytrip you will have to click on the element and then you will have to click on the date as shown in the below code. If you will see selection of date is happening in one element and it is displaying the selected date in the other element( if you will see the P tag then you will realize that it is displaying the selected date in the P tag and not in the same element).

```
  @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
         driver.manage().window().maximize();
         driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

         driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         WebElement date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]"));

         date.click();

        // System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath()));

         Thread.sleep(3000);
         String dateVal = "Tue Jun 16 2020";
        selectDateByJS(driver, dateVal);

        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }

    public static void selectDateByJS(WebDriver driver, String dateVal) {

        JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='DayPicker-Day' and @aria-label='"+dateVal+ "']")));

    }
```

Comment: Anytime my friend. If you face any issue then feel free to contact me anytime :)

Comment: The line "arguments[0].click()" will click a single element, but what If I have to click on multiple buttons using javascript executor. Should everytime I be using below two lines ?                                                                                                  JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);  js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='DayPicker-Day' and @aria-label='"+dateVal+ "']")));

Comment: You have got two options then. Either you create multiple functions for all the elements or you can use the same function but you need to add one more parameter that will accept the class attribute value in string format @class='DayPicker-Day'. It totally depends on DOM of the application. If you face any issue then we can discuss on it more :)